# Pop remove items from the original list Python

Tags: python, list

So I just noticed this doesn't work because POP is removing elements from both lists.

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = l1

l2.pop(1)
print(l1)

>> [1, 3, 4]
```

How this could be solved? I would like to iterate over l1 removing n elements from l2.

```
for i in range(0, len(l1), 2):
    l2.pop(i)
```

But I got out of index because both list one and two were modified

Comment: *It's the same list*. See: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `l2 = l1[:]` to make a copy otherwise as @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned you are pointing at the same list

Comment: I see, thank guys!

Comment: Note, this isn't going to fix your problem. You aren't iterating over `l1`, you are iterating over a `range` object. The problem is that the indices in `l2` won't match up when you change it's size. Also, this algorithm is highly inefficient, being quadratic time. A more efficient approach is to not involve `.pop` and just do `l2 = l[::2]`, or if you feel like doing with a loop, *grow* `l2` using `.append` as you iterate over `l1` Removing from inside a list is inefficient, appending to the end is very efficient

Comment: That was really, really, useful. Thanksss! :) @juanpa.arrivillaga